# Could the Cuban coronavirus antiviral be a mass cure for COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology, virus, antivirals

Sometime around 1981, the Cubans invented an antiviral treatment for coronavirus. What is its relative efficacy against COVID-19? What are the pathways and obstacles for it making its way to being a mainstream mass cure for the pandemic?

---

> Havana, March 14 (RHC)--Cuba said on Friday it has enough reserves of an antiviral drug which has been used to treat COVID-19 in China to cover the island’s demand and also that of other countries.

<sub>[Cuba biotech industry has enough antivirals to treat COVID-19](http://www.radiohc.cu/en/noticias/nacionales/216780-cuba-biotech-industry-has-enough-antivirals-to-treat-covid-19) (March 14, 2020)</sub>

---

> Havana, March 18 (RHC)-- Cuba has full capacity to supply Interferon alpha 2B and other 22 medicines to the national health system in the fight and treatment of COVID-19. It is also s working on a vaccine against that disease.

<sub>[Cuba can produce 23 drugs to treat coronavirus and is working on a vaccine against it](http://www.radiohc.cu/en/noticias/salud/217063-cuba-can-produce-23-drugs-to-treat-coronavirus-and-is-working-on-a-vaccine-against-it) (March 18, 2020)</sub>

Comment: What has your research revealed? What is this thing the Cubans invented?

Comment: @CareyGregory: http://www.radiohc.cu/en/noticias/nacionales/216780-cuba-biotech-industry-has-enough-antivirals-to-treat-covid-19 "Cuba said on Friday it has enough reserves of an antiviral drug which has been used to treat COVID-19 in China to cover the island’s demand and also that of other countries."

Answer (score 1):

All interferons interfere with viral replication but until the Cubans show that their drug `Interferon alpha 2B` is any better than anything else, then there's nothing to recommend it over anything else used in the treatment of COVID-19.

The list of drugs recommended by CPAM are:

> For direct antiviral treatment of SARS-CoV-2, CPAM recommends use
>   of lopinavir; ritonavir [2 capsule (dose undefined) by mouth twice daily] in combination with nebulized alfa-interferon (5 million units in Sterile Water for Injection inhaled twice daily). CPAM ( China International Exchange and Promotive
>   Association for Medical and Health Care) has based this recommendation on weak evidence from retrospective cohort, historically controlled studies, case reports, and case series that suggest clinical benefit of lopinavir; ritonavir in the treatment of other
>   coronavirus infection [i.e., 2002 SARS-CoV and 2012 Middle East respiratory syndrome coronavirus
>   (MERS-CoV)]. (4) (8) (7)

..

> In addition to CPAM, a group of Korean physicians with experience in treating SARS-CoV-2 infected
>   patients have developed recommendations for the treatment of COVID-19. According to these
>   physicians, antiviral medications are not recommended for use in young, healthy patients with mild
>   symptoms and no underlying comorbid conditions. However, treatment with lopinavir 400 mg; ritonavir
>   100 mg (2 tablets by mouth twice daily) or chloroquine (500 mg by mouth twice daily) should be
>   considered for use in older patients or patients with under underlying conditions and serious symptoms.
>   If chloroquine is unavailable, they recommend considering use of hydroxychloroquine (400 mg by mouth
>   once daily). Use of ribavirin and interferon were not recommended as first-line treatments because of
>   the risk for side effects; however, use of these medications may be considered if treatment with
>   lopinavir; ritonavir, chloroquine, or hydroxychloroquine are ineffective. (12) (13)

It is unclear if the alpha interferon used in China is the same as the one the Cubans are selling.

https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0007/988648/COVID-19-Drug-Therapy_Mar-2020.pdf